# PHP is_dir: Strange behaviour with special characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

I've got a strange behaviour regarding is_dir with special characters: äöüàéè.

If the special chars are written first (eg. 'à tést', 'école wat') then the code works fine (detects folder).

But if any chars besides the special are written before the special chars (eg. 'tést', 'the école') then it doesn't work.

Here's the code I'm using. I tried to force convert the text to make it work but it won't.

```
if ( is_dir(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "{$text}")) ){ //Do Something }
```

Comment: Maybe it would be essential if you delete those special characterss by some function and create dir with A-Z 0-9 -_ only

Comment: I'd like to but I'm required to work with those special characters.

Comment: I tried to run this code
`$a = "äöüàéè";
$b = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $a);`
But I got error: Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
Are you sure you can use UTF-8 there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using mb_convert_encoding.

```
if ( is_dir(mb_convert_encoding( "{$text}", "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8" )) ){ //Do Something }
```

$text instead "{$text}" should also do same i guess

As a last advice take a look at this comment ;
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#85752